# Accessing comments on an object via reverse relationship with Tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie, django-comments

I'm building an API using Tastypie with Django and I've run into a bit of an issue.

I have a model called a `Moment` (basically a blog post, with a title and body text), and I want to be able to attach comments to it and retrieve them via the API. I'm using `django.contrib.comments` with Django 1.6.5 and Tastypie 0.11.1.

Now, according to the Tastypie documentation, [this should be straightforward](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#reverse-relationships). What I've implemented is pretty close to that. This is my `models.py`:

```
class Moment(models.Model):
    """ 
    Represents a Moment - a statement by a user on a subject
    """
    ZONE_CHOICES = ( 
                   ('Communication', 'Communication'),
                   ('Direction', 'Direction'),
                   ('Empathy', 'Empathy'),
                   ('Flexibility', 'Flexibility'),
                   ('Motivation', 'Motivation'),
                   ('Ownership', 'Ownership'),
                   ('Persistence', 'Persistence'),
                   ('Reliability', 'Reliability'),
                   ('Teamwork', 'Teamwork'),
    )   
    STATUS_CHOICES = ( 
                     ('Open', 'Open'),
                     ('More Info', 'More Info'),
                     ('Closed', 'Closed'),
    )   
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    zone = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                            choices=ZONE_CHOICES)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Student, blank=True, null=True, related_name="sender")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                              default='Open',
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(Sponsor, blank=True, null=True, related_name="recipient")
    comments = generic.GenericRelation(Comment, object_id_field='object_pk')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Override the save() method to set the recipient dynamically
        """
        if not self.recipient:
            self.recipient = self.sender.sponsor
        super(Moment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-datetime"]
```

And this is my `api.py`:

```
class MomentResource(BaseResource):
    """ 
    Moment resource
    """
    sender = fields.ForeignKey(StudentResource, 'sender', full=True, readonly=True)
    comments = fields.ToManyField('myapp.api.CommentResource', 'comments', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        """
        Metadata for class
        """
        queryset = Moment.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'moment'
        always_return_data = True
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        filtering = { 
            'zone': ALL,
        }


class CommentResource(ModelResource):
    """ 
    Comment resource
    """
    moment = fields.ToOneField(MomentResource, 'moment')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Comment.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'comments'
```

However, the comments always come back blank.

Now, I know that the model seems to be correct because in the Django shell, the following returns the comments on a Moment:

```
Moment.objects.all()[0].comments.all()
```

I think the problem is therefore in `api.py`, but I haven't been able to track it down. Can anyone see where I've gone astray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working with the following:

```
class MomentResource(BaseResource):
    """ 
    Moment resource
    """
    sender = fields.ForeignKey(StudentResource, 'sender', full=True, readonly=True)
    comments = fields.ToManyField('myapp.api.CommentResource', 'comments', null=True, full=True)

    class Meta:
        """
        Metadata for class
        """
        queryset = Moment.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'moment'
        always_return_data = True
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        filtering = { 
            'zone': ALL,
        }


class CommentResource(BaseResource):
    """ 
    Comment resource
    """
    moment = fields.ToOneField(MomentResource, 'content_object')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Comment.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'comments'
```

I'm pretty sure the issue was with returning the `Moment` object from `CommentResource`, which was resolved by changing the attribute to `content_object`.