# Struggling to get django_comments to work with Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-comments

I'm using Django REST Framework for the first time on a project and I'm struggling with one particular part. The project is an issue tracker-type applicaton and it uses `django_comments` to allow for comments on issues. I'm now building an API on top of it to allow for creating a mobile app.

I've created the following serializers:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from todolist.models import Project, Issue
from rest_framework import serializers
from django_comments.models import Comment

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'owner')


class CommentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment


class IssueSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    comments = CommentSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Issue
```

And here's my project-wide `urls.py`, where I define the routes:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url 
from todolist.views import HomeTemplateView, UserViewSet, ProjectViewSet, IssueViewSet, CommentViewSet
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'projects', ProjectViewSet)
router.register(r'issues', IssueViewSet)
router.register(r'comments', CommentViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'projectile.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^projectile/', include('projectile.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    # Comments
    (r'^comments/', include('django_comments.urls')),

    # Login
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),

    # Logout
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login', {'login_url': '/accounts/login/'}),

    # To-do list
    url(r'^projects/', include('todolist.urls')),

    # Home page
    url(r'^$', HomeTemplateView.as_view(
        template_name="todolist/home.html",
        )), 

    # Router URLs
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),

    # REST framework auth URLs
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_auth_token),

    # API docs
    url(r'^docs/', include('rest_framework_swagger.urls'))
)
```

I'm seeing the following error when I run a test which tries to get all the comments:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "contenttype-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

Also, when I fetch an issue, it doesn't include the comments.

Now, this error appears to me to be that when fetching a comment, it's unable to match up the comment to its parent. I've [experienced similar problems when using Tastypie in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453709/accessing-comments-on-an-object-via-reverse-relationship-with-tastypie), and I'm unsure how to resolve it with DRF.

Comment: can you post your urls.py file.

Comment: do you have a serializer called `contenttype` ?

Comment: @levi No. `django_comments` is the old Django comment system, which was moved to a separate app as of 1.6. It's built using the Django contenttypes framework. The contenttype field is a foreign key to the ContentType model from the contenttypes framework.

Comment: check my answer, you need to exclude contenttype field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Comment` serializer, specify comment instances fields explicitly and exclude field `contenttype`.

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('field_1','field_2','field_3') #here goes your comment fields and dont include contenttype field
```

The problem is that DRF will try to apply  hyperlinks to represent all relationships, and for `contenttype` field you don't have a view or a serializer and you dont need it either.